# Bash: execute files via for-in-loop

Tags: bash, syntax

```
for executablefile in ./*.out; do executablefile; done
```

It should be self-explanatory from the title what I am trying to do in bash. Unfortunately, none of the tutorials online comes close to this. Can you post a working example and explain your changes?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there to get a hint: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Voted up for shellcheck tool! I also added shellharden analysis tool in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the proper variable syntax?

```
for executablefile in ./*.out; do "$executablefile"; done
```

Comment: Properly speaking you should use double quotes around the variable interpolation, in case the wildcard matches anything which contains shell metacharacters.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Of course not; then I'd have posted a separate answer instead.